# Why is "join on or" much slower two "join on"?

Tags: mysql

The following query is quick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   apple
       LEFT JOIN banana b1
              ON apple.id = b1.one
       LEFT JOIN banana b2
              ON apple.id = b2.two
WHERE  b1.id IS NULL
       AND b2.is IS NULL
```

While the following is slow:

```
SELECT *
FROM   apple
       LEFT JOIN banana
              ON apple.id = banana.one
                  OR apple.id = banana.two
WHERE  banana.id IS NULL
```

Can anyone explain why doing an "join on" statement with an "or" is so much slower than joining against two tables?

Comment: "so much slower"? How much slower?

Comment: What database is this, and what does the explain plan show?

Comment: "quick" "slow" Ah, yes, those useful and precise engineering metrics!

Comment: Why three upvotes? This question doesn't have even nearly enough information to answer. It also shows no prior research.

Comment: Fast=0.1 seconds. Slow=Several seconds. (apple=10k rows, banana=100k rows). "join on or" has been a consistent problem with many different tables, therefore the generic question.

Answer (score 5):

In the first query at joins mysql will look-up using only one column from `banana` table (N look-ups, where N is the nb of records from `apple` table).

In the second query it will have to do a look-up using 2 columns from `banana` table further more in the worst case it will have to do NxN look-ups where N is the nb of records from `apple`

You can read more about the algorithms used [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/nested-loop-joins.html).

Also you can check the `EXPLAIN` output in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5767/6) provided by *Stan McGeek*

**UPDATE:** also keep in mind :

> If you use LEFT JOIN to find rows that do not exist in some table and
>   you have the following test: col_name IS NULL in the WHERE part, where
>   col_name is a column that is declared as NOT NULL, MySQL stops
>   searching for more rows (for a particular key combination) after it
>   has found one row that matches the LEFT JOIN condition.

Comment: I don't see why the 'OR' query would require N x N lookups. I would expect a worst case of 2N, not n^2.

Comment: @alzaimar in the worst case scenario i assumed that the first condition is false (N look-ups) that means the second condition will be evaluated (N look-ups) since its `OR`

Comment: not quite since for each look-up for the first condition N look-ups will be made for the second condition ... think of it as in a `for` loop inside a `for` loop at least this is my assumption since the docs are not very specific about this

Comment: It's actually NxM where N = number of apples, M = number of bananas, each apple is checked against each banana for a match, assuming no use of an index. But the complexity is equal in both cases, because the `OR` does not need two separate scans (or let's say it is NxMx2 because two checks must be made at each iteration).

Answer (score 2):

This surprising situation arises because the `OR` operator combines two columns, thus preventing the use of any index on either column.

Let's assume banana has two indexes, one on `banana.one` and another one on `banana.two`.

In the first query, the optimiser would be able to use an index for each distinct `JOIN`, because they are executed in two distinct passes. Each `JOIN` will use one of the two indexes on `banana` (complexity = Nx2 = N, where N = number of apples).

In the second version, there is only one `JOIN`, and one single pass. But a `JOIN` can only use one index. Since neither index is insufficient (only one of the two `JOIN` conditions is covered), it will not use any index and go for a full scan of table `banana` (complexity = NxMx2 = NxM, where M = number of bananas).

You can check this with an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` of each query.

Notice a two-column index on `(banana.one, banana.two)` would be just as useless.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query

```
SELECT *
FROM      apple
LEFT JOIN banana b1 ON apple.id = b1.one
LEFT JOIN banana b2 ON apple.id = b2.two
WHERE  b1.id IS NULL
   AND b2.is IS NULL
```

seems to be looking for all the `apples` that that don't have a matching `banana` on columns `banana.one` and `banana.two`. If that's the case, why aren't you doing the obvious and simply stating the problem clearly:

```
select *
from apple a
where not exists ( select *
                   from banana b
                   where b.one = a.id
                 )
  and not exists ( select *
                   from banana b
                   where b.two = a.id
                 )
```

Any decent query optimizer should be able to make short work of that, assuming indices on `apple`'s primary key `id` and `banana`'s foreign key columns `one` and `two`.

And If you had a covering index on banana columns `one` and `two`, e.g.

```
create index banana_one_two on banana ( one , two )
```

Your poorly performing query the slow one would like work fine too.

Examining the execution plan you're getting will likely give you useful information about what's wrong.